# how to implement type 1 and type 2 dimension table using pig

Tags: apache-pig

i need to do a small POC by implementing type 1 and type dimension table using PIG.

Type 1 - Overwriting the old value. In this method no history of dimension changes is kept in the database. The old dimension value is simply overwritten be the new one. This type is easy to maintain and is often use for data which changes are caused by processing corrections(e.g. removal special characters, correcting spelling errors).

Before the change:

```
Customer_ID Customer_Name   Customer_Type
1   Cust_1  Corporate
```

After the change:

```
Customer_ID Customer_Name   Customer_Type
1   Cust_1  Retail
```

Type 2 - Creating a new additional record. In this methodology all history of dimension changes is kept in the database. You capture attribute change by adding a new row with a new surrogate key to the dimension table. Both the prior and new rows contain as attributes the natural key(or other durable identifier). Also 'effective date' and 'current indicator' columns are used in this method. There could be only one record with current indicator set to 'Y'. For 'effective date' columns, i.e. start_date and end_date, the end_date for current record usually is set to value 9999-12-31. Introducing changes to the dimensional model in type 2 could be very expensive database operation so it is not recommended to use it in dimensions where a new attribute could be added in the future.

Before the change:

```
Customer_ID Customer_Name   Customer_Type   Start_Date  End_Date    Current_Flag
1   Cust_1  Corporate   22-07-2010  31-12-9999  Y
```

After the change:

```
Customer_ID Customer_Name   Customer_Type   Start_Date  End_Date    Current_Flag
1   Cust_1  Corporate   22-07-2010  17-05-2012  N
2   Cust_1  Retail  18-05-2012  31-12-9999  Y
```

so can we implement a small POC based on these two.

Please Help!!

Comment: please help. I need to do a POC.

Answer (score 0):

Pig does not support ovewrinting an existing data, hence you cannot implement it using only Pig. But if you create your table in Hive, and use [Hcatalog](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore#HCatalogLoadStore-HCatStorer) to insert data into the table keeping processing data in Pig, It should works.

Comment: can we delete the old file and again load the new update file?
will this follow the logic for type1?